# Codename one "theme" passed on parameter doesnt work

Tags: java, themes, codenameone, blogs, android-theme

i have in package `com.mycompany.myapp` this file `MyApplication.java` that has a start function like this

```
public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        new AjoutBlogForm(theme).show();
    }
```

but the `theme` passed in parameter doesnt want to work it shows 'incompatible types: recources cannot be converted to Blog'

in my class `AjoutBlogForm` i have this :

```
public class AjoutBlogForm extends BaseForm {

    Form current;
    public AjoutBlogForm(Blog blog) {
        super("Newsfeed",BoxLayout.y()); //herigate men Newsfeed w l formulaire vertical
    
        Toolbar tb = new Toolbar(true);
        current = this ;
        setToolbar(tb);
        getTitleArea().setUIID("Container");
        setTitle("Ajout Blog");
        getContentPane().setScrollVisible(false);
        
        //

        TextField titre = new TextField("", "entrer Titre!!");
        titre.setUIID("TextFieldBlack");
        addStringValue("titre",titre);
        
        TextField contenu = new TextField("", "entrer contenu!!");
        contenu.setUIID("TextFieldBlack");
        addStringValue("contenu",contenu);

        TextField imageBlog = new TextField("", "entrer image!!");
        imageBlog.setUIID("TextFieldBlack");
        addStringValue("imageBlog",imageBlog);
        
        
        Button btnAjouter = new Button("Ajouter");
        addStringValue("", btnAjouter);
        
        
        //onclick button event 
        btnAjouter.addActionListener((e) -> {
            try {
                
                if(titre.getText().equals("") || contenu.getText().equals("") || imageBlog.getText().equals("")) {
                    Dialog.show("Veuillez vérifier les données","","Annuler", "OK");
                }
                
                else {
                    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();; //Loading  after insert data
                    final Dialog iDialog = ip.showInfiniteBlocking();
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    
                    //njibo iduser men session (current user)
                    Blog b = new Blog(
                                  String.valueOf(titre.getText()).toString(),
                                  String.valueOf(contenu.getText()).toString(),
                                  format.format(new Date()),
                                  format.format(new Date()),
                                  String.valueOf(imageBlog.getText()).toString(),
                                  0);
                    
                    System.out.println("data  blog == "+b);

 
                    ServicesBlog.getInstance().ajoutBlog(b);
                    
                    iDialog.dispose();

                    refreshTheme();//Actualisation
                }
            }catch(Exception ex ) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }


    private void addStringValue(String s, Component v) {
        add(BorderLayout.west(new Label(s,"PaddedLabel"))
        .add(BorderLayout.CENTER,v));
        add(createLineSeparator(0xeeeeee));
    }
    
}
```

and in my entity is this :

```
public class Blog {

    private int id;
    private String titre, contenu;
    private String dateCreation,dateModification;
    private String imageBlog;
    private int etat;

    public Blog() {
    }

    public Blog(String titre, String contenu) {
        this.titre = titre;
        this.contenu = contenu;
    }

    public Blog(String titre, String contenu, String imageBlog, int etat) {
        this.titre = titre;
        this.contenu = contenu;
        this.imageBlog = imageBlog;
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public Blog(String titre, String contenu, String dateCreation, String dateModification, String imageBlog, int etat) {
        this.titre = titre;
        this.contenu = contenu;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.dateModification = dateModification;
        this.imageBlog = imageBlog;
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public Blog(int id, String titre, String contenu, String dateCreation, String dateModification, String imageBlog, int etat) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titre = titre;
        this.contenu = contenu;
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
        this.dateModification = dateModification;
        this.imageBlog = imageBlog;
        this.etat = etat;
    }

    public String getImageBlog() {
        return imageBlog;
    }

    public void setImageBlog(String imageBlog) {
        this.imageBlog = imageBlog;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitre() {
        return titre;
    }

    public String getContenu() {
        return contenu;
    }

    public String getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public String getDateModification() {
        return dateModification;
    }

    public int getEtat() {
        return etat;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        this.titre = titre;
    }

    public void setContenu(String contenu) {
        this.contenu = contenu;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(String dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateModification(String dateModification) {
        this.dateModification = dateModification;
    }

    public void setEtat(int etat) {
        this.etat = etat;
    }
}
```

i tried rebuilding the project multiple times, it works for other functions of the templates just it doesnt work for AjoutBlogForm.
i was expecting the theme to work and to be able to add the blog.

Answer (score 0):

The class `AjoutBlogForm` expects an object of type `Blog` in the constructor. Notice that `theme` is defined in `MyApplication` as a `Resources` type. Those are separate classes that have no common ancestor as `Blog` is a class you defined with a distinct purpose.

From the code you posted I don't understand why you pass `blog` in the constructor since it doesn't seem like you're using it at all. I suggest removing the entry from the constructor and changing the call to pass no arguments.